# Constructing a codomain for a bijective function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Give an example of a codomain $S$ so that the function $h: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow S$ is bijective.

\begin{align*}
h(n) &= \begin{cases}
       n  & n \textrm{ is even.}\\
         -2n & n \textrm{ is odd.}
       \end{cases}
\end{align*}

I think that the codomain would be all even integers except 0 and {-4,-8,-12...}. Is this correct? $S=\{2k:k\in \mathbb{Z} \} \setminus \{-4k:k\in \mathbb{N} \} \setminus \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: list the images $h(n)$ for some values of $n$, like $h(0)=0$, $h(1)=-2$, $h(2)=2$, $h(3)=-6$, $h(4)=4$, etc. Do you notice a pattern?

(In fact, looking at your earlier question might be another hint.)

Comment: In your answer, $h(3)=-6$, and obviously I missed that $h(0)=0$, so $S=\{2k:k\in \mathbb{Z} \} \setminus \{-4k:k\in \mathbb{N} \}$ should be correct, no?

Comment: haha, thanks for pointing that out. And yes, you're right. We'll of course get all the even natural numbers, and then $-2n$ for $n$ odd will range over those negative integers which aren't divisible by $4$ (since $n$ odd).